# Check how many times <li> tag is printed, if more times create new row

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have created wp menu in administration panel named "Main menu", then I am trying to retrieve it in header. I get items but not able to get child below parent.

In my HTML template, menu structure is like this:

```
<ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="./">Home</a>  </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a> 

    <li><a href="#">Products</a> 
    <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu"> 
        <li>
            <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                <li><a href="product-catalog.html">Product 1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="product-catalog.html">Product 1</a></li> 
                <li><a href="product-catalog.html">Product 1</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#features">Services</a> 
    <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">   
        <li> 
            <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 3/a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 4</a></li>          
            </ul>
        </li> 
        <li> 
            <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 8</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
           <!--<p class="rd-megamenu-header">Samouklapajući limovi</p>-->
          <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
            <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="classic-news.html">Service 8</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#">News</a>
    <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>

    <li><a href="contacts.html">Content</a></li>
</ul>
```

in header.php I retreive menu that is created in WP admin panel. It is organized well but the only trouble I have is with printing

tag. I want to create new row of block below if four

are printed

```
<li> // Here I need to count how many times is printed, if more than 4 then I shoud create new row
                  <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
                  </ul>
                </li>



   <ul class="rd-navbar-nav">
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    $submenu = false;
    foreach( $menuitems as $item ):
        $link = $item->url;
        $title = $item->title;
        // item does not have a parent so menu_item_parent equals 0 (false)
        if ( !$item->menu_item_parent ):
        // save this id for later comparison with sub-menu items
        $parent_id = $item->ID;
    ?>

    <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title">
        <?php echo $title; ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $parent_id == $item->menu_item_parent ): ?>

        <?php if ( !$submenu ): $submenu = true; ?>
        <ul class="rd-navbar-megamenu">
        <?php endif;?>
            <li> // Here I need to count how many times is printed, if more than 4 then I shoud create new row
              <ul class="rd-megamenu-list">
                <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></a>
              </ul>
            </li>
           <?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id && $submenu ): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( $menuitems[ $count + 1 ]->menu_item_parent != $parent_id ): ?>
</li>
<?php $submenu = false; endif; ?>
```

Any kind of advice is helpful